# Django celery task: Newly created model DoesNotExist

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

Why is a model instance I've created, when queried from a celery task started directly afterwards, not found? For example:

```
# app.views

model = Model.objects.create()    # I create my lovely model in a view
from app.tasks import ModelTask   # I import my Async celery task
ModelTask.delay(model.pk)         # I start the task
```

That all looks fine, and surely if I queried at any point after the `create()` call the model should exist in the database.

**Update 1**: I'm using the default `transaction.autocommit` behaviour, that Django provides, for my view.

But the task below throws an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception:

```
# app.tasks

class ModelTask(Task):
    def run(self, model_pk):
        from app.models import Model
        Model.objects.get(pk=model_pk)
```

In my tests, as expected, `model_pk` is a correct positive integer ID.

### Conclusion

I assume there is some asynchronous/"separate process" issues arising here, but I don't know what it is. If feel as though there is some obvious mistake I'm making.

I don't think that database transactions are the answer, because Django's default "autocommit" approach ensures DB actions are performed as soon as the `create()` method is called.

Comment: Did you check that it does actually save to the database? And that the pk value is the same that is being returned? Have you looked in the log files for warnings or errors?

Comment: The model is visible in Django admin directly afterwards. And although I haven't checked exactly, the PK looks in the right range. I forgot to mention that sometimes the model is found, which is why I think it's a race issue.

Comment: Can you give the code for `model` (simplified as much as possible, while still replicating the bug)?  Particularly, I'm assuming that: pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)?

Answer (score 18):

These answers need to be updated. Django now has `transaction.on_commit()` which is built for this exact problem, they even provide an example with a task:

```
transaction.on_commit(lambda: some_celery_task.delay('arg1'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem in my code. After long investigation, I found out that race condition was happening because I was using [@transaction.commit_on_success](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) decorator. So the transaction was committed only after view returned. Which was happening after I was calling celery task.

Once I've removed "commit_on_success" decorator, everything started to work as expected. Because Django's [default transaction behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior) is to commit transaction after any database altering operation.

You might also want to make sure you are not using TransactionMiddleware, because it does similar thing to [@transaction.commit_on_success](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) decorator. If you want to keep using it, you should look into using [@transaction.autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.autocommit) decorator in your views with celery tasks, or [@transaction.commit_manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually).

Comment: I am using default transaction management (autocommit), which is why it's so odd. I have added `transaction.commit()` regardless, and, although it shouldn't have any effect, it seems to prevent the error. Maybe because it delays the process for a few ticks.

Comment: @MarcusWhybrow Then it's possible that your view actually resides inside a `transaction.commit_on_success`, could you check that, for example by calling `transaction.is_managed()` under Django 1.5 and earlier? For example, `add_view` in the Django Admin has `commit_on_success` wrapping around it. Thus if being invoked by the `post_save` signal which is triggered by the `add_view`, your code is inside a managed transaction..

Comment: @okm Didn't know about the `transaction.is_managed()` check. Sounds useful. Disclaimer: It's been months since I was dealing with this issue, so I'll just keep it in mind going forwards.